# Как создать вертикальную прокрутку в основном окне WinApi

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Подскажите пожалуйста, как создать рабочую вертикальную полосу прокрутки при создании основного окна средствами WinApi ? Я создаю окно через CreateWindow указываю флаг WS_VSCROLL, сама полоса прокрутки с бегунком появляется, но она по факту почему то не рабочая, потому что реально содержимое клиентской области окна она не прокручивает. Хотя, еслиe в этом же окне создать дочернее окно класса "edit" и поставить такой же флаг WS_VSCROLL, то в этом окне прокрутка нормально работает текст прокручивается. Не могу понять, что я не так делаю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Прокрутку содержимого нужно выполнять самостоятельно (с помощью функции `ScrollWindow` или `ScrollWindowEx`) при получении сообщения `WM_VSCROLL`. Также нужно отслеживать изменение размеров окна и/или содержимого, чтобы устанавливать scrollbar-у соответствующие этим размерам параметры (диапазон прокрутки и размер страницы).

---

Для примера предположим что содержимое не меняется, поэтому будем отслеживать только размер окна:

```
case WM_SIZE: {
    SCROLLINFO scrInfo;
    scrInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SCROLLINFO);

    scrInfo.nPage = HIWORD(lParam); //размер страницы устанавливаем равным высоте окна
    
    scrInfo.nMin = 0; //диапазон прокрутки устанавливаем по размеру содержимого
    scrInfo.nMax = CONTENT_HEIGHT; //(вместо CONTENT_HEIGHT подставь нужное значение)

    scrInfo.fMask = SIF_RANGE | SIF_PAGE; //применяем новые параметры
    SetScrollInfo(hwnd, SB_VERT, &scrInfo, TRUE);
}
return 0;
```

прокрутка содержимого:

```
case WM_VSCROLL: {
    SCROLLINFO scrInfo;
    scrInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SCROLLINFO);

    scrInfo.fMask = SIF_ALL; //получаем текущие параметры scrollbar-а
    GetScrollInfo(hwnd, SB_VERT, &scrInfo);

    int currentPos = scrInfo.nPos; //запоминаем текущее положение содержимого

    switch (LOWORD(wParam)) { //определяем действие пользователя и изменяем положение
        case SB_LINEUP: //клик на стрелку вверх
            scrInfo.nPos -= 1;
            break; 
        case SB_LINEDOWN: //клик на стрелку вниз 
            scrInfo.nPos += 1;
            break;
        case SB_THUMBTRACK: //перетаскивание ползунка
            scrInfo.nPos = scrInfo.nTrackPos;
            break;
        default: return 0; //все прочие действия (например нажатие PageUp/PageDown) игнорируем
    }   

    scrInfo.fMask = SIF_POS; //пробуем применить новое положение
    SetScrollInfo(hwnd, SB_VERT, &scrInfo, TRUE);
    GetScrollInfo(hwnd, SB_VERT, &scrInfo); //(см. примечание ниже)

    int yScroll = currentPos - scrInfo.nPos; // вычисляем величину прокрутки
    ScrollWindow(hwnd, 0, yScroll, NULL, NULL); //выполняем прокрутку
}
return 0;
```

*Примечание: функция SetScrollInfo автоматически исправляет выход nPos из диапазона nMin...nMax, так что фактически установленное значение nPos может отличаться от запрошенного. Поэтому там и нужен повторный вызов GetScrollInfo.*

Comment: t3f, Спасибо! Но, видимо я не правильно что то объяснил. Вы написали, что "Прокрутку содержимого нужно выполнять самостоятельно". Почему тогда автопрокрутка работает в дочернем окне ?

Comment: @Optimus1, потому что в предопределённых классах, таких как edit (насколько я понял, под "дочерним окном" подразумевается экземпляр одного из них), встроен уже готовый механизм прокрутки. Там тип содержимого (а значит и алгоритм его прокрутки) строго определён, поэтому можно было встроить готовую прокрутку. Тогда как простое окно может содержать всё что угодно, поэтому заранее неизвестно какая именно прокрутка ему понадобится.